# Ansible - How target GCE based on meta data

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible

Is it possible to target google compute instances with Ansible based on a metadata variable and value i.e. apply this playbook to items tagged web servers when they have a meta data variable of sitename with value site1?

Answer (score 5):

seems to work.

```
tasks:
    - name: test siteprefix
     action: debug msg="This instance is mysite"
     #when: gce_machine_type == "n1-highcpu-4"
     when: gce_metadata.site == "mysite"
```

if variable might not exist then

```
 when: gce_metadata.site is defined and gce_metadata.site == "mysite"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler answer is already provided by AdiFatLady. Just for completeness the other option would be to use [dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html). Write your own script for dynamic inventory and return the hosts based on your own custom filtering logic as members of the hostgroup that your playbook is written for.